# Efficient numeric routines for computing $_2F_0$

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

As part of a project related to kinematic fluid dynamics, the following integral appeared in the moment expansion
$$
\int_0^{\alpha} t^m\,_2F_0\left(\begin{matrix}-\ell-\frac{1}{2},m+2\\-\end{matrix};\frac{t-1}{\epsilon}\right)dt
$$
Now while I have no illusions that this has a closed form, it is sufficient to be able to evaluate it numerically. Since $\alpha$ is usually positive and not large compared to 1, a numeric integration should be fairly efficient provided there is an efficient way to calculate $_2F_0$. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find good routines to do that. Most special function packages have the related function $_1U_1$, but that often requires evaluating it at very large arguments, raising concerns about accuracy.

Does anyone know of a good numerical method for calculation $_2F_0$ directly?

Comment: "that often requires evaluating it at very large arguments" - well, the asymptotic behavior of the Tricomi function is [rather well-known](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.7), so why not just convert your integral for ${}_2 F_0$ into an integral for $U$ and then use an integrator that is robust to singularities?

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, which is quite efficient for computing $_2F_0(a,b,z)$:

-- If z=0, return 1.

-- If z is real, return $(-z)^{-a}U(a,1+a-b,-1/z)$, where $U$ is the function
you mention.

-- Otherwise (or if z is too close to 0) use the double-exponential method
to compute $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{a-1}(1-zt)^{-b}\,dt/\Gamma(a)$$

I have a 3-line Pari/GP program to do this if you want.